# PHPMailer and attachments not displaying properly when opened

Tags: php, phpmailer

My apologies, I am very new and had difficulty with the editing process etc. I hope the following is more acceptable. The PHP application attaches to the 'receiving email box' and processes the received emails accordingly. It creates a new email that contains comments, attaches the original email and then sends the newly created email back to the 'from address' extracted from the original email. The original email may have been sent from any number of email programs available to users. It may also have pdf/text attachments. When I send the 'newly' created email to Gmail, it displays the attached original email (and it's attachments if any) correctly but not when it is sent to MS Outlook or Horde.

After execturing a new phpmailer class, I added the following:

```
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Encoding = 'base64';
```

Coding to save the original email:

```
$mime = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, "");
file_put_contents('./workfolder/OriginalEmail.eml', $mime);
```

I have also tried this coding when saving the original email:

```
$headers = imap_fetchheader($inbox,$email_number, FT_PREFETCHTEXT);
$body = imap_body($inbox, $email_number);
$structures = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $email_number);
file_put_contents('./workfolder/OriginalEmail.eml', $headers . '\n' . $body . '\n' . $structures);
```

I have checked the mime type which displays: message/rfc822

Coding used to attach original email:

```
$mail->AddAttachment('./workfolder/OriginalEmail.eml');
```

I have also tried this when attaching the original email:

```
$mailer->AddAttachment('./workfolder/','OriginalEmail.eml','base64','message/rfc822');
```

Wednesday - I am having such problems with adding comments.
Here is what I tried:

```
$strOrigEmail = file_get_contents('./workfolder/OriginalEmail.eml');
echo '<BR><BR>$strOrigEmail: ' . $strOrigEmail;
$mail->addStringAttachment('$strOrigEmail', 'YourEmail.eml');
```

And  the echo displays everything from the original email- headers, body etc. and the attachments (including their filename) but it is endocded. Below is a snippet below of what it looks like:

```
   name=junk.txt Content-Disposition: attachment; size=11; filename=junk.txt junk file --=_7-AofrqAv83eu5i63j73DWn--
```

I have also tried this and no better - displays same thing as above:

```
  $strOrigEmail = file_get_contents('./workfolder/OriginalEmail.eml');
  echo '<BR><BR>$strOrigEmail: ' . $strOrigEmail;
  $mail->addStringAttachment(base64_decode('$strOrigEmail'), 'YourEmail.eml');
```

Comment: Please explain IN DETAIL  what NOT CORRECTLY means. " correctly but not when it is sent to MS Outlook or Horde."     Please post prefarrable the HTML code or an image or both.

Comment: It looks like you're doing it the right way to me, though your second attachment call needs the filename in the first param – the second param lets you give the attachment a different name to the original file. You could skip writing it to disk using the `addStringAttachment()` method instead of `addAttachment()`.

Comment: I thank you all for responding. In Detail -  when viewing the attachment (which was the original email) using MS Outlook - the email contents are all blank - it is if you composing a  new email. When viewing with Horde,  it is encoded, I think as a base 64 . Does that help to explain what I am seeing ?? Should I attach images for you ??

Comment: Syncho - thank you all for responding. I will try the addStringAttachment() method and report back to you. Probaably won't be until Wednesday, It just seems so strange. I keep asking myself what is so different on how Gmail display the attachment compared to MS Outlook/Horde ? A setting or security issue ??

Comment: Added the results of Wednesday  to my original question - Having terrible problem in separately posting results from my original question.- thank you for understanding.